# Error suggests I'm missing a using directive or assembly reference, but I'm not....

Tags: c#, android, api, xamarin

I'm pretty new to working with more than one project in a solution. I have two projects: **AutoPoster.Droid** and **AutoPoster.Core**.

In AutoPoster.Droid I have an adapter class that references LocationInfo in AutoPoster.Core. I'm now getting this error and not sure why:

The type or namespace 'Core' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or assemblu reference?)

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Android.App;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace AutoPoster.Droid.Adapters
{
    public class PostInfoAdapter : BaseAdapter<Core.Model.LocationInfo>
    {
        private readonly Activity activity;
        public List<Core.Model.LocationInfo> LocationInformation { get; private set; } //Getting Error Here
        public PostInfoAdapter(Activity context, IEnumerable<Core.Model.LocationInfo> localInfo)//Getting Error Here
        {
            LocationInformation = new List<Core.Model.LocationInfo>(localInfo);//Getting Error Here
            activity = context;
        }

        public override int Count
        {
            get { return LocationInformation.Count; }
        }

        public override Core.Model.LocationInfo this[int position]//Getting Error Here
        {
            get { return LocationInformation[position]; }
        }

        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            var view = convertView ?? activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem2, null);

            var localInfo = LocationInformation[position];

            var name = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Android.Resource.Id.Text1);
            name.Text = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(localInfo.FullName) ? localInfo.FullName : localInfo.ShortName;

            var rxcui = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Android.Resource.Id.Text2);
            rxcui.Text = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(localInfo.FullName) ? localInfo.ShortName : String.Empty;

            return view;
        }

        public void ReloadData(IEnumerable<Core.Model.LocationInfo> locationInformation)//Getting Error Here
        {
            LocationInformation.Clear();
            LocationInformation.AddRange(locationInformation);
            NotifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may have a reference, but if you don't have `using AutoPoster.Core` at the top, or fully qualify references to classes in that namespace, then it won't know what you're referring to.

Comment: Thanks barrick, but I tried this and it didn't work :/

Comment: Okay, right click on the References folder in your project, Add Reference, then click on Solution on the left-hand side of the window, and add in the AutoPoster.Core project.

Comment: I'm using Xamarin Studios IDE. I don't see Solution on the left-hand side

Comment: Oh NVM I found it under the project tab. Awesome! Thank you so much barrick

Comment: I'm glad you did, as I've never used Xamarin!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use namespaces like that. You can't specify just part of a namespace, from after `AutoPoster`. You either need a `using` directive for `AutoPoster.Core.Model`:

```
using AutoPoster.Core.Model;

namespace AutoPoster.Droid.Adapters
{
    public class PostInfoAdapter : BaseAdapter<LocationInfo>
    {
        ...
    } 
}
```

Or you need to *fully* qualify the classname:

```
namespace AutoPoster.Droid.Adapters
{
    public class PostInfoAdapter : BaseAdapter<AutoPoster.Core.ModelLocationInfo>
    {
        ...
    } 
}
```

EDIT: And yes, you do actually have to have a reference from one project to the other...

Comment: I tried both of these solutions and still get the same errors. If I add the using directive AutoPoster.Core.Model it says I'm missing an assemble reference. :/

Comment: @Learnin2Code: Have you checked that you really *are* declaring a namespace of `AutoPoster.Core.Model`? And do you *definitely* have an assembly reference to the other project?

Comment: Yes My LocationInfo.cs looks like this

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace AutoPoster.Core.Model
{

 public class LocationInfo
 {
  public string FullName { get; set; }
  public string ShortName { get; set; }
 }
}

Comment: @Learnin2Code: Okay. And what kind of assembly reference do you have? Is it to a file, or to the project?

Comment: I got it fixed Jon Skeet. I didn't have it added as a reference. Thank you for your help though!